# Which manifold is formed by the set of resolutions of the identity operator into orthogonal projectors?

Tags: functional-analysis, manifolds, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

A resolution of the identity operator $I$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a decomposition
$$I = \sum_{i=1}^n P_i,$$
where the $\{P_i\}$ are a set of orthogonal rank-one projection operators. What is the manifold (or Lie group) structure of the set of all resolutions of the identity, or equivalently sets $P_i$?

A naive guess is to express each $P_i$ as an outer product $|\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i|$ and identify every resolution of the identity with an orthonormal basis $\{|\psi_i\rangle\}$ - the set of which is diffeomorphic to $\mathrm{U}(n)$ (since you can rotate any orthonormal basis into another one via an appropriate unitary operator). But I don't think is quite right, because you could multiply any basis vector by a phase factor $e^{i \theta}$ (or in the real case, $-1$) without changing the corresponding projector $P_i$, so the orthonormal basis contains redundant information/degrees of freedom. (Permuting basis elements also leaves the decomposition unchanged, but we can ignore this possibility because it can't be done continuously.) Is the answer just $\mathrm{U}(n) / \mathrm{U}(1)^{\times n}$ to remove the $n$ redundant phase factors, or something more complicated? If so, is there a simpler expression for this quotient group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's just $U(n)/U(1)^n$. This is not a quotient group because $U(1)^n$ is not a normal subgroup. This manifold is known as the (complete) [flag variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety#Prototype:_the_complete_flag_variety) of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and much is known about it.

Comment: Just to clarify, by $\mathrm{U}(n)/\mathrm{U}(1)^n$ you mean that it's a quotient space in the topological sense rather than a quotient group?

Comment: Yes, although it's much more than just a topological space: it's even a smooth manifold and, more surprisingly, even a smooth projective complex algebraic variety.

Comment: Is there any nice mathematical structure to the set of orthogonal projection operators that sum to the identity, if you don't require that the projection operators all be rank-1? I believe that by analogy, this would be the set of all topological spaces of the form $$\mathrm{U}(n)/\prod_i \mathrm{U}(n_i)$$ for all partitions $\{n_i\}$ of $n$. Does this topological space form a "nice" smooth manifold or smooth projective complex algebraic variety, either for an individual (generic) choice of partition or for the set of all partitions?